# jQuery image slide not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and trying to play around with it to get some practice. I have inserted a jQuery image slider on my local website by using a source code provided at slidesjs.com but it's not working.

Also, I like to make it more organise so how can I link my jQuery page with the html if I were to separate all the jQuery out into a new file?

http://jsfiddle.net/3WaWf/1/

Following is what i attempted:

```
<html>
    <header>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"></header>

        <style>
        /* Prevents slides from flashing */
        #slides {
          display:none;
        }
      </style>

      <script>
        $(function(){
          $("#slides").slidesjs({
            width: 940,
            height: 528
          });
        });
      </script>

    <body>
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <h1 class="logo" style="vertical-align:middle">LogoHere</h1>

            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li><a href="index.html" class="action">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" class="about">Who we are</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html" class="blog">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html" class="services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="contact">Get in touch</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="slides">
                <img src="hkslide1.jpg">
                <img src="hkslide2.jpeg">
                <img src="hkslide3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should provide us with a http://jsfiddle.net showing your relevant code.

Comment: About organising your HTML, create new JS document and copy/paste all scripts from your HTML document to your new JS document and give it a name eg. scripts than call it in your HTML document like this `<script src="scripts.js"></script>`

Comment: @mdesdev would that include copying over the <Style> tags?

Comment: No for styles make style.css document and copy/paste your inline styles there, and of course after that remove inline styles from your HTML document.

Comment: @mdesdev i dont think it is recognising the scripts when I separate it, is there any sort of header I have to put in the script.js file? Atm all I have is    <script>
        $(function(){
          $("#slides").slidesjs({
            width: 940,
            height: 528
          });
        });
      </script>

Comment: Look at my answer below, that's how should look like you HTML, of course without inline CSS and with some meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct section for js and css include is  not  also check the correct path of your including, if the are not found you'll find 404 errors in your browser console.

Code:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>
```

The demo code, if setup correctly, works fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/tzPE2/

Comment: this is exactly what i've done. Can you show me how you would do the link ref in the head? Its not working the way I did it..Following comment is how I did the link ref

Comment: <head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
 </head>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jquery.slides.min.js is on the same directory as the main page, and to separate out the JQuery code you just need to put it on a separate .js file reference it on the page like this:  where you would have put the code.

Comment: You should download it to your local machine, or reference the files from the website you copied the code from.

Answer (score 0):

These should go in between `<head>` and `</head>` tags, not in `<header>`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
```

Edit

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" media="screen">

  <style>
    /* Prevents slides from flashing */
    #slides {
      display:none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="nav-bar">

      <h1 class="logo" style="vertical-align:middle">LogoHere</h1>

      <ul class="nav-menu">
          <li><a href="index.html" class="action">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html" class="about">Who we are</a></li>
          <li><a href="blog.html" class="blog">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html" class="services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html" class="contact">Get in touch</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="slides">
          <img src="hkslide1.jpg">
          <img src="hkslide2.jpeg">
          <img src="hkslide3.jpg">
      </div>

    </div>

<!-- SCRIPTS -- If you're putting scripts in HTML, put them below this line -->

  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

In this example the **jquery.slides.min.js** and **style2.css** must be in your root folder, same place where is your index.html

Answer (score 0):

Might need to defer your code so it executes after the elements have been loaded. Try adding your js in the footer (keep the stylesheet in the head) and give that a try.